# XML Feed to Database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to put all of my videos and the video info into a MySQL database using PHP and the YouTube Data API. I'm using the `simplexml_load_file` function. I can't get it to work. It doesn't put in any results. (Excuse the deprecated PHP/MySQL.)
Here is the code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '*NOT NEEDED*', '*NOT NEEDED*');
mysql_select_db('demoScript');
mysql_query("TRUNCATE videos");
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/demoScript/uploads";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$targeti = substr_count($url, "<entry>");
for($i=0; $i<$targeti; $i++){
    $title = $xml->entry->title;
    $id = $xml->entry->id;
    $date = $xml->entry->published;
    $views = $xml->entry->yt['viewCount'];
    $rating = $xml->entry->gd['average'];
    $faves = $xml->entry->yt['favoriteCount'];
    $desc = $xml->entry->content;

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videos` VALUES ('".$id."','".$title."','".$date."','".$views."','".$rating."','".$faves."','".$desc."')");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap-responsive.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <div class='brand' style='float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 8px; font-size: 20px;'>demoScript</div>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>        
    </ul>
    <div class='hero-unit'>
        <center><h2>Most Viewed Video</h2></center><p />
    </div>
    <script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just from reading this, not much can be said (other than the loop), what is the problem, are you getting errors?

Comment: Try to analyze your code by debugging. Look at xdebug (http://xdebug.org/), witch you can run script step by step and watch variables values. Then you will see, where the problem is.

Comment: @Ibu No. When I refresh the page (which should update the database) then check the MySQL database, there isn't anything in the database.

Comment: Here is [how simple xml works](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) as you can see you are not looping through your xml object

Comment: @Ibu What's wrong with the loop?

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use the $i in your loop.
You could do something like `$xml->entry[$i];` but simplexml_load_file already gives you a object. You can loop over its children with:

```
foreach($xml->nameOfParentTag as $entry){
   $title = $entry->title;
   $id = $entry->id;
   $date = $entry->published;
   $views = $entry->yt['viewCount'];
   $rating = $entry->gd['average'];
   $faves = $entry->yt['favoriteCount'];
   $desc = $entry->content;
}
```

Instead of using a substring counter.

Comment: I tried that with a MySQL query at the end and ended up with one result in the database, hoping for twelve.

Comment: Did you echo the insert queries to see if there is something wrong there? The problem is in te loop or in the query.